# What is the address that appear when print a pointer without * or &

Tags: c++, pointers

When print a pointer without `*` or `&` shows an address, I don't know what is this address.

**For example:**

```
int *n;
int num = 10;
n = &num;

cout << n << endl;    // Prints 0020F81C
cout << &n << endl;   // Prints 0020f828
```

**The result:**

[image]

I know `cout << &n << endl;` to print the address of place in the memory.
But what about `cout << n << endl;` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

n is referring to "&num", therefore it's the address to the place in memory where num is pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

You've answered your own question. It is an address. The address in memory of whatever the pointer points to, or zero: in this case, the address of 'num'.

Your second 'cout' prints the address of the pointer itself.

Comment: Thank you also for you answer.